# Рабочие примеры по архитектуре приложений ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, c#, asp.net-mvc, архитектура, .net

Всем привет. В последнее время меня интересует разделение приложений на слои BLL, DAL и тд. Мне пока сложно разобраться с тем как они устроены в реальных приложениях, хотя я и понимаю  общую концепцию. Будьте так любезны выложить свои примеры, особенно организации BL слоев.

Всем спасибо!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У нас это делится по довольно формальным критериям.

DAL - это компоненты для работы с конкретной СУБД. Грубо говоря, это управляемый поставщик [ADO.NET](http://ADO.NET) + реализации наших интерфейсов, расширяющих возможности управляемых поставщиков.

BLL - это код, связанный с конкретными сущностями предметной области, отображаемой в структуре БД. Кроме того, к уровню бизнес-логики относятся классы, выполняющие работу, которая не связана с реализацией пользовательского интерфейса.

UI - это код, использующий конкретную технологию построения пользовательского интерфейса, например [ASP.NET](http://ASP.NET), и обращающийся к уровню BLL по запросам пользователя.

Классы, сгенерированные с помощью ORM по структуре БД, могут относиться как к DAL, так и к BLL в зависимости от специфики. Если структура классов строго повторяет структуру БД, и они не содержат кода, который пишется вручную, то это DAL. Если кодогенератор имеет гибкие настройки, позволяющие разнести структуру классов и структуру БД, а сами эти классы дополнены специальной логикой, то это BLL.

Comment: Мне нужен именно кодовый пример, а не описание, поэтому надеюсь получить от вас пример проекта с таковой структрой.

Comment: Лучше на сайте ASP.NET посмотрите tutorial. Он будет гораздо понятнее, чем какой-нибудь наш проект, т.к. там специально не будет никакой специфики.

Comment: Хорошо посмотрю

Answer (score 1):

[S#arp Architecture](http://code.google.com/p/sharp-architecture/)

Comment: Если я не ошибаюсь, этот пример не веб приложение. А я просил веб-приложение.

Comment: "Sharp Architecture," this is a solid architectural foundation for rapidly building maintainable web applications leveraging the ASP.NET MVC framework with NHibernate.

Comment: Позволяет установить шаблон для студии и создавать проект с уже готовой базовой архитектурой.

Comment: Понятно. Ну тогда спасибо. Попробую.

Answer (score 0):

Вот пример приложения с неплохой структурой. Все модули разбиты, а размер проекта достаточен, чтобы изучить все нюансы:

> https://github.com/MarlabsInc/SocialGoal